# Check if word is already in DB (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function which checks if word in a string is in the DB.

So, for example, I have a list with basic words in my DB. I type a sentence and would like to get all the words from that sentence which are not yet in the DB.

Any tips on how to work this out?

Comment: [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert search string to an array using this function

```
$str = "Hello user how are you.";
$find_it = explode(" ",$str);
```

Now use mysql query to find if this exist in DB or NOT...

```
 $filterExisting = "'" . implode("', '", $find_it ) . "'";
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field NOT IN (". $filterExisting .")";
   $result = $db->query($sql);
```